# Display realtime candlesticks using Python and Matplotlib on the same figure

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I would like to display realtime candlesticks chart using Python and Matplotlib

I did this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, draw, show
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

from numpy import nan
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#plt.ion()
#plt.ioff()

while True:

    #plt.clf()

    #ax = plt.gca()

    opn =  104.04852126730329
    close = np.random.uniform(90, 110)
    high = max(opn, close)*np.random.uniform(1, 1.05)
    low = min(opn, close)*np.random.uniform(0.95, 1)
    DOCHLV = [[1, 100, 99, 101, 98, 0.0], [2, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [3, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [4, 104, 98, 105, 95, 0.0], [5, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [6, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [7, 100, 99.99976844819628, 100.91110690369828, 97.82248296015564, 1152.3258524820196], [8, 99.99976844819628, 100.51985544064271, 100.51985544064271, 96.65206230438159, 1578.5836411214814], [9, 100.51985544064271, 104.04852126730329, 104.54571702827914, 99.49632496479201, 1477.5651279091041], [10, opn, close, high, low, 372.6679262982206]]
    print(DOCHLV)

    #plt.close()

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    _ = candlestick(ax, DOCHLV, width=0.8, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=1.0)
    _ = ax.set_xlim(0, len(DOCHLV)+1)  

    #plt.show()
    plt.show(block=False)

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Unfortunately candlesticks are drawn on several figures.

Is there a way to fix this ?

I tried to remove

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

from while loop (in order to plot on the same ax)
but chart is not updated

I also tried to use plt.draw() instead of plt.show(...)
but window doesn't appear

I also tried to close (previous) window before plotting... but
in such a case, chart is blinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`. Here is a prototype of how you could use it, [based on this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from numpy import nan
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

def test(dummy):
    opn =  104.04852126730329
    close = np.random.uniform(90, 110)
    high = max(opn, close)*np.random.uniform(1, 1.05)
    low = min(opn, close)*np.random.uniform(0.95, 1)
    DOCHLV = np.array([[1, 100, 99, 101, 98, 0.0], [2, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [3, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [4, 104, 98, 105, 95, 0.0], [5, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [6, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0], [7, 100, 99.99976844819628, 100.91110690369828, 97.82248296015564, 1152.3258524820196], [8, 99.99976844819628, 100.51985544064271, 100.51985544064271, 96.65206230438159, 1578.5836411214814], [9, 100.51985544064271, 104.04852126730329, 104.54571702827914, 99.49632496479201, 1477.5651279091041], [10, opn, close, high, low, 372.6679262982206]])
    plt.cla()
    candlestick(ax, DOCHLV, width=0.8, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=1.0)
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(DOCHLV)+1)
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, test, interval=25)
anim.save('teste.mp4', fps=15)
```

Comment: There is 2 issues: First it's not realtime (I only get a video) Second this video is not updated correctly. Between 2 frames chart should be cleared.

Comment: It works fine, after adding `plt.cla()` before candlestick(...) and after putting `plt.show()` instead of `anim.save(...)`

Comment: But the problem is that you remove while loop... and I need this loop!

Comment: @working4coins have you succeded in your approach with `plt.cla()` and `plt.show()` without animation?

Comment: and you can hand `FuncAnimation` a generator which returns the values you want so you don't need the `while` loop

Comment: I recommend `from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc`